# OpenMP reduction with overloaded operator

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, operator-overloading, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize the loop in the following function with OpenMP

```
 void CEnergymulti::forcetwobody(vector<CMolecule*>  m_mols,CPnt force0,CPnt torque0)
{
 const int nmol=m_mols.size();
 vector<CMolecule*> twomols(2);
 CPnt forcetemp,torquetemp;
 twomols.clear();
 force0.zero();
 torque0.zero();
 forcetemp.zero();
 torquetemp.zero();
 #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:force0,torque0) private(twomols)
 for(int j=1;j<nmol;j++)
       { twomols.push_back(m_mols[0]);
         twomols.push_back(m_mols[j]);
         CMolecule::polarize_mutual(twomols,false, 1000);
         twomols[0]->computeMol_Force_and_Torque(forcetemp,torquetemp);
         force0+=forcetemp;
         torque0+=torquetemp;
         forcetemp.zero();
         torquetemp.zero();
         twomols.clear();
        }
     REAL converter=COUL_K*IKbT;
     force0*=converter;
     torque0*=converter;
     return;
     }
```

When I compile the code, it gives the following message:

```
EnergyD_multi.cpp: In static member function ‘static void
CEnergymulti::forcetwobody(std::vector<CMolecule*,
std::allocator<CMolecule*> >, CPnt, CPnt)’: EnergyD_multi.cpp:226:
error: ‘torque0’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’
EnergyD_multi.cpp:226: error: ‘force0’ has invalid type for
‘reduction’
```

I understand that variables 'force0' and 'torque0' are neither double or integer type of data, but of type 'CPnt', a class that is defined to represent three-dimensional vectors in space. For class 'CPnt', operator '+' and '-' have already been defined by operator overloading. So my questions is: is it true that reduction in OpenMP cannot handle such overloaded operators? Is there any alternate ways to parallelize this loop with OpenMP without doing reduction on each component of 'force0' and 'torque0'?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you get this working?  I changed your code to do the overload operation with OpenMP.  Let me know if it works.  Please see the link to understand the main idea in case there is a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot @raxman. With the parallelization scheme you suggested the code could be compiled. However, I'm still a bit confused about the parallelization of the loop with `nowait`. This is because I still believe that for every thread the variables in the loop 'twomols' and 'forcetemp' should be considered as 'private', but you didn't list them as private.

Comment: Everything inside "#pragma omp parallel" is private by definition. Only force0 and torque0 are shared because they are outside of the omp pragma

Comment: If you like my answer feel free to give me an up vote.  If you think it's the best answer then select it as the best answer.

Comment: @raxman. Actually even if I could compile the code based on your modification, when I ran the code I still got segmentation fault that leads to core dump. However, if I add twomols' and 'forcetemp' as private the code could run smoothly, though the result is still different from that of a serial code. It might be something wrong with certain function called in my code, but do you think it's necessary to have 'private' variables when 'nowait' is used? Thanks.

Comment: @raxman. I wish I could give you an up vote. However, my current reputation doesn't allow me to do that. I'll do that after my reputation has increased. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult for me to debug your code without all the code and knowing what your are doing.  I originally posted my working example so you can understand the concept.  You should be able to get the main idea from the link.  You should get the same result as the serial code.

Comment: No wait just removes the barrier of the for loop so when a thread finishes it goes right to the critical block.

Comment: I changed the code slightly.  I moved most of the private variables inside the for loop.  Maybe that helps.

Comment: Are you sure your using "vector<CMolecule*>" correctly? This should be a vector of pointers but then it looks like you push values "twomols.push_back(m_mols[0]);"  Maybe you mean to use &m_mols[0] or vector<CMolecule>?

Answer (score 8):

It's true that OpenMP reduction can't handle such overloaded operators.  However, there is an alternative.  One way to rewrite a reduction in OpenMP is to use the `nowait` and `atomic` paramters.  http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ReductionClause
.This is just as fast as the normal way.

If you replace `atomic` with `critical` you can use more complex overloaded operators.  This is not as fast as using `atomic` but it's still works well in my experience.

I did this so I could use operators that operate on 4 or 8 floats at once (with SEE or AVX).
[reduction with OpenMP with SSE/AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430069/reduction-with-openmp-with-sse-avx)

Edit: I changed your code to reflect what I think would do what you want.

```
void CEnergymulti::forcetwobody(vector<CMolecule*>  m_mols,CPnt force0,CPnt torque0)
{
    const int nmol=m_mols.size();
    force0.zero();
    torque0.zero();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        CPnt force0_private;
        CPnt torque0_private; 
        force0_private.clear();
        torque0_private.clear();
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for(int j=1;j<nmol;j++)
        { 
            CPnt forcetemp,torquetemp;
            forcetemp.zero();
            torquetemp.zero();
            vector<CMolecule*> twomols(2);
            twomols.clear();
            twomols.push_back(m_mols[0]);
            twomols.push_back(m_mols[j]);
            CMolecule::polarize_mutual(twomols,false, 1000);
            twomols[0]->computeMol_Force_and_Torque(forcetemp,torquetemp);
            force0_private+=forcetemp;
            torque0_private+=torquetemp;
        }
        #pragma omp critical 
        {
           force0 += force0_private;
           torque0 += torque0_private;
        }

    }
    REAL converter=COUL_K*IKbT;
    force0*=converter;
    torque0*=converter;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think the second pragma (i.e. `#pragma omp parallel for nowait`) should be `#pragma omp for nowait`, i.e. without the parallel (The parallel construct has already been setup outside it). My compiler complains that you cannot have a nowait alongside a parallel for, as there is supposed to be an implicit barrier after the parallel for. Seems like nowait and parallel for are conflicting directives.

Comment: @VarunGulshan, you're correct, it should be `#pragma omp for nowait`. I just fixed it.

Comment: Arent you loosing the logarithmic complexity like this?
---
Worst case is that every thread waits to enter the critical section and then they are sequentially adding their results.
---
So in the end you have `O(nmol / thread_num) + O(thread_num)` instead of `O(nmol / thread_num) + O( log (thread_num))`
---
This could make a huge difference on a powerful computer (i.e. supercomputer)

Answer (score 3):

These days, you could also use the `declare reduction` directive (OpenMP 4.0+); e.g.

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(mysum:CPnt:omp_out += omp_in) initializer(omp_priv.zero())
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(mysum:force0,torque0) private(twomols)
for(int j=1;j<nmol;j++)
...
```