# What is the usage of reduction in openmp?

Tags: openmp, reduction

I have this piece of code that is parallelized.

```
int i,n; double pi,x;
double area=0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for private(x) reduction (+:area)
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    x= (i+0.5)/n;
    area+= 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
}
pi = area/n;
```

It is said that the reduction will remove the race condition that could happen if we didn't use a reduction. Still I'm wondering do we need to add lastprivate for area since its used outside the parallel loop and will not be visible outside of it. Else does the reduction cover this as well?

Comment: You don't want to use last private.  Read this link to learn about reductions, firstprivate, lastprivate, and other things in OpenMP
http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ReductionClause.  See my answer for more info about reductions.

Answer (score 3):

Reduction takes care of making a private copy of `area` for each thread. Once the parallel region ends area is reduced in one atomic operation. In other words the `area` that is exposed is an aggregate of all private `area`s of each thread.

```
thread 1 - private area = compute(x)
thread 2 - private area = compute(y)
thread 3 - private area = compute(z)

reduction step - public area = area<thread1> + area<thread2> + area<thread3> ...
```

Comment: Thanks. So pi gets the correct value and not 0? I thought values defined outside of the parallel sections would lose the value outside of the loop unless defined as lastprivate.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need lastprivate.  To help you understand how reductions are done I think it's useful to see how this can be done with `atomic`. The following code

```
float sum = 0.0f;
pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:sum)
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    sum += //
}
```

is equivalent to

```
float sum = 0.0f;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    float sum_private = 0.0f;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        sum_private += //
    }
    #pragma omp atomic
    sum += sum_private;
}
```

Although this alternative has more code it is helpful to show how to use more complicated operators.  One limitation when suing `reduction` is that `atomic` only supports a few basic operators.  If you want to use a more complicated operator (such as a SSE/AVX addition) then you can replace `atomic` with `critical` [reduction with OpenMP with SSE/AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430069/reduction-with-openmp-with-sse-avx)

Comment: Why the last private is not needed?