# What is Parallel for usage in different for loops?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have some code fragments here where what I think as correct is not given as the answer. I need some help to clarify this.

```
dotp=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
dotp+= a[i]+b[i];
}
```

given answer for parallelizing this code is :

```
dotp=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:dotp)
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
dotp+= a[i]+b[i];
}
```

I think it needs the dotp to be added as a firstprivate to be visible inside the for loop

```
dotp=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:dotp) firstprivate(dotp)
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
dotp+= a[i]+b[i];
}
```

If this is not correct why we do not have to use firstprivate ?

Comment: You already asked basically the same question a few days ago.  Why don't you go through some OpenMP tutorials (like the one I listed)  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532229/what-is-the-usage-of-reduction-in-openmp/16544624#16544624

Answer (score 0):

The `reduction` clause marks `dotp` as **shared** and performs a final summation.

The initial value of each shared `dotp` within the for loop is 0. The final step in the summation is to add the previous version (original) value of `dotp`, in your case this is 0. However it could be any value.

You do not (and should not) need to say it is first private, to enforce the initial zeroing of `dotp`.