# omp library c++ pragma for

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I have this code, but I need help to use OpenMP `#pragma`s to increase its speed.  I want to parallelize the `for` loops over variables `i` and `j`. The values of `n` and `m` can be much larger, too.  For example, `n = 1000`, `m = 500`.

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        matrix[i][j] = {static_cast<double>(distribution(gen)),
                        static_cast<double>(distribution(gen))};
    }
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
    n = 50;
    m = 50;
    ReS = 0;
    ImS = 0;

    for (int nu = 0; nu < 1; nu++) {
#pragma omp for num_threads(4)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                double* matrixPtr = &matrix[i][j].first;
                double* matrixPtrSecond = &matrix[i][j].second;

                for (double theta = 0; theta < PI; theta += theta_plus) {
                    for (double phi = 0; phi < 2 * PI; phi += theta_plus) {
                        double angle = *matrixPtr * cos(phi) * sin(theta) +
                                       *matrixPtrSecond * sin(phi) * sin(theta);
                        ReS += cos(angle);
                        ImS += sin(angle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, we miss the variable declarations. Also we need to understand what exactly you want to do. On first look, you seem to declare the `ReS` and `ImS` variables outside the `parallel`, making them shared , while it looks like you want to do a [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532229/what-is-the-usage-of-reduction-in-openmp)

Comment: By the way, if you have the sin value, then you can compute the cos one and vice versa since `cin² a  + sin² a = 1`. There is maybe a way to use a dot product here. This strategy should make the code faster since sin/cos functions are particularly expensive.

Comment: In fact, you can even pre-compute `cos(phi)`, `sin(phi)`, `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)` so to put them in a table that you can reuse. I think the computation can be significantly more optimized without even using more cores.

Comment: Also note that using `num_threads(4)` is a bad practice (unless your code only support exactly 4 threads). Please consider setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` instead which is more flexible.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Nice trick with the sin + cos. Didn't know that. But it's probably better to use [`sincos`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sincos) if available. [`std::polar(1., angle)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/polar) should also work (compiles to `sincos` on GCC)

Comment: I think floating point variables as loop variables are somewhat of a code smell as they accumulate floating point error. I would rather use integer loop counters that are then multiplied with e.g. `theta_plus` to arrive at `theta`.

Comment: The `sin(phi)` and `cos(phi)` calls as well as the `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)` calls can also be eliminated. As an example for `phi`: In the first iteration of the innermost loop, let `x = std::complex(1., 0.)`. From iteration to iteration, calculate `x *= std::polar(1., theta_plus)` (obviously moving the `polar` call outside the loop). Then `cos(phi) == x.real` and `sin(phi) == x.imag`, within rounding errors. This works because multiplying with a complex number rotates by its phase angle. And the real and imaginary components give the cosine and sine

Comment: @Homer512 `sincos` is AFAIK non standard and I think it uses the old x87 instruction which is often significantly slower than calling `sin`+`cos` separately in practice (and prevent vectorization). Good to know for `std::polar` though. I will make some tests to check the performance. It turns out GCC and ICC already merge the `sin` + `cos` calls to 1 call of `sincos` at compile time, but not Clang.

Comment: @Homer512 Calling `std::polar` generates an assembly code very similar to calling `sin` and  `cos` separately. Thus, GCC/ICC calls `sincos` (ICC calls its own optimized version `__libm_sse2_sincos`) and Clang performs 2 separate calls (except with `-ffast-math`). Note that all the compilers seem not to vectorize such a loop (even with `-O3 -mavx2 -ffast-math`)... possibly because this is hard to get <=1 ULP error with double-precision using SIMD instructions on such a trigonometric function.

Comment: @Homer512 The code of the glibc `sincos` is available [here](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sincos.c.html). It is not very clear how it works, but It looks like they use a merged sincos table and they call two separate `do_sin`+`do_cos` functions regarding the input argument (in most cases). It should be at least cache-efficient since the same item of the LUT should be fetched by the two sub-calls (same for the `sin`+`cos` separate calls actually). Thus, I do not expect a huge performance improvement from using `sincos` though it should help a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // ...
```

In your original code causes the whole associated block to be executed in parallel by *each* of the threads of a team.  That seems counterproductive.  At minimum, the intention is unclear.

The ...

```
for(int nu = 0; nu < 1; nu++)
```

... loop unconditionally executes exactly one iteration.  That seems pointless.

The main computation performs frequent updates to shared variables `ReS` and `ImS`.  That would be an absolute performance killer, but the structure is well suited for using a reduction to resolve that problem.

You said (I think) that you wanted to parallelize the loops over `i` and `j`.  The code you present parallelizes only the outer of those, but of course that carries the inner loop with it.  The loops structure is compatible with parallelizing over the `(i,j)` pairs instead of just over `i`, so I'll show that below, though I'm by no means sure that that will make much difference.

Here's how that might apply to the main loop:

```
#if 0
 // Remove this
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
#endif
n = 50;
m = 50;
ReS = 0;
ImS = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) num_threads(4) reduction(+:ReS,ImS)
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        double *matrixPtr = &matrix[i][j].first;
        double *matrixPtrSecond = &matrix[i][j].second;

        for (double theta = 0; theta < PI; theta += theta_plus) {
            for (double phi = 0; phi < 2 * PI; phi += theta_plus) {
                double angle = *matrixPtr * cos(phi) * sin(theta)
                             + *matrixPtrSecond * sin(phi) * sin(theta);
                ReS += cos(angle);
                ImS += sin(angle);
            }
        }
    }
}
#if 0
}
#endif
```

There may also be opportunities to substantially speed even the serial version of the computation, as discussed in comments on the question, but I'm focusing here on the use of OpenMP directives, which is what the question seems to be asking about.