# #pragma omp for/parallel problems

Tags: c++, optimization, openmp, pragma

```
for (int nu = 0; nu < 20; nu++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            double matrixPtr = matrix[i][j].first;
            double matrixPtrSecond = matrix[i][j].second;
            double localReS1 = 0.0;
            double localImS1 = 0.0;
            for (double theta = 0; theta < 2 * M_PI; theta += theta_plus) {
                for (double phi = 0; phi < M_PI; phi += theta_plus) {
                    double angle = matrixPtr * cosPhi * sintheta +
                                   matrixPtrSecond * sinPhi * sintheta;
                    localReS1 += cos(angle);
                    localImS1 += sin(angle);
                }
            }

#pragma omp critical
            {
                ReS += localReS1;
                ImS += localImS1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see my code above, please help me, how can I parallelize the Phi and theta loops, because they eat a lot of space, and they must be inside the i,j loops, the nu loop cannot be removed, it must always be present. If you have any ideas how to speed up this code by a factor of 2 at least, I would be glad to hear your answers. I haven't tried parallelizing on CUDA yet, because I'm trying to solve the problem without it, in the extreme case I'll probably do it with its application.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `omp` to get better performace in matrix calculations. I would rely on the C++ compiler to use vectorized operations to do your actual matrix calculations (for better cache locality per core).  Also represent your matrix as a  `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`  and do the 2D index calculations yourself. (Really you should get rid of std::pair too). Anyway if you're really interested in performance : profile your code ;)

Comment: Didn't we answer an [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78111002/omp-library-c-pragma-for) by you already? What's wrong with that answer?

Comment: This really does feel like spam. Not only did OP ignore comments below his previous questions asking for a minimal, reproducible example, the code also looks much more incomplete. Where is the calculation of `cosPhi`, `sintheta`, `sinPhi` and `sintheta`?